# Hashmap value conversion error

Tags: java, android, hashmap

My Android app is receiving json from google places api.In that rating is usually float value.so when i receive this rating as double data type in following code it says The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap is not applicable for the arguments (String, double).so I need to to convert this p.rating to string in order to add hashmap to arraylist to pass it as key,value pair.how I can achieve that.

```
  // loop through each place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results) {
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();


                            map.put(KEY_REFERENCE, p.reference);

                            // Place name
                            map.put(KEY_NAME, p.name);
                            map.put(KEY_EXTRA,p.rating);//here it says The method put(String, String) in the type HashMap<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (String, double)


                            // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                            placesListItems.add(map);
                        }
```

Comment: `String.valueOf("p.rating")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
String rating = String.valueOf(p.rating);
```

Comment: @blackbelt yeah sorry, was too quick on my fingers :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best thing to do is `String.valueOf(p.rating)`. Be aware that this might throw a `NullPointerException` if `p` or `p.rating` is `null`

Comment: if `p` is `null`, not `p.rating`

Comment: It will throw an Exception for both cases